# How can I render only a specific `BLOCK` in a Perl's Template Toolkit?

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

How can I render only a specific `BLOCK` in a template?

Suppose I have this `BLOCK` in `text.tt`, a [Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/) file:

```
[% BLOCK someblock %] some block test blah blah blah [% END %]
```

I want to be able to use `process()` to handle just that portion:

```
$tt->process("text.tt/someblock", {...}, {...});
```

Is this the right way to handle this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think its the EXPOSE_BLOCKS option that you maybe after?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Template;

my $tt = Template->new({
    INCLUDE_PATH  => '.',
    EXPOSE_BLOCKS => 1,
});

$tt->process( 'test.tt/header', { tit => 'Weekly report' } );

for my $day qw(Mon Tues Weds Thurs Fri Sat Sun) {
    $tt->process( 'test.tt/body', { day => $day, result => int rand 999 } );
}

$tt->process( 'test.tt/footer', { tit => '1st Jan 1999' } );
```

test.tt:

```
[% BLOCK header %]
[% tit %]
[% END %]

[% BLOCK body %]
* Results for [% day %] are [% result %]
[% END %]

[% BLOCK footer %]
Correct for week commencing [% tit %]
[% END %]
```

Will produce this report (with random numbers):

> Weekly report
>
> - Results for Mon are 728
> - Results for Tues are 363
> - Results for Weds are 772
> - Results for Thurs are 864
> - Results for Fri are 490
> - Results for Sat are 88
> - Results for Sun are 887
>
> Correct for week commencing 1st Jan 1999

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know where I can find a complete list of Template Toolkit config options? EXPOSE_BLOCKS isn't mentioned on this list: http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Config.html

Comment: That is probably the best list but unfortunately like you noticed EXPOSE_BLOCKS is missing from it :(   I probably picked up EXPOSE_BLOCKS from the Perl Template Toolkit book (http://template-toolkit.org/book.html).   Just flicking thru index it says page 69... hmmm example is pretty bare but it is mentioned there.